# On linux, can I get keys to behave differently if tapped?

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard

So I just read a wonderful article about tricking out the modern keyboard:

http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/

On of the most interesting suggestions for me is this vision of a duality for the control key:

1. When pressed in conjunction with another key, the control key acts as it normally does.
2. When briefly tapped, the control key sends escape.

This would be a big deal for me, because it would save me a significant amount of movement as I use vim.

Is there any way I can implement this behavior in linux?

Comment: This makes a neat feature. Please, share your findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/alols/xcape Xcape seems to be exactly what you're after.